# insert and if statements to calculate grades

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically I'm creating a student test-software and a part of my table structure is as follows:

```
RESULTS_TBL: QPaper_ID, Marks, Class, Subject, Grade, Student_ID [THIS TABLE STORES THE CALCULATED RESULTS BASED ON HIS PERFORMANCE]

ANSWERS_TBL: QPaper_ID, Marks, Class, Subject, Student_ID [THIS TABLE STORES ONLY THE CORRECT ANSWERS GIVEN BY THE STUDENTS AND THE MARKS FOR EACH QUESTION ]
```

I want to calculate the results mainly the Grade and insert the values from ANSWERS_TBL into the RESULTS_TBL . Below is a part of my code:

```
DECLARE @A_G INT, @B_G INT, @C_G INT, @D_G INT
SET @A_G = 40
SET @B_G = 30
SET @C_G = 10
INSERT INTO RESULTS ( QPaper_ID, Marks,Student_ID, Class, Grade)
select QPaper_ID, sum(Marks), Student_ID, Class,
case
when  sum(Marks) > @A_G then 'A'
when sum(Marks) between @B_G and @A_G then 'B'
when sum(Marks) between @C_G and @B_G then 'C'
else  'D'
END
from ANSWERS where QP_ID = 1000 and Login_ID = 'a'
GROUP BY QPaper_ID ,Marks, Student_ID, Class
```

When I run this query, all the rows from ANSWERS are inserted into RESULTS which I don't want. I want only one record which calculates the sum of marks for each question along with the grade obtained. BTW is the code correct.

THANKS

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to group by Marks?

Comment: @HABO - i dont know?? what should I do?

Comment: Actually, if the results are just derived from the `answers` table, you might just want to use a view.

Comment: Tip: For clarity I would have written the grade comparisons so that they don't overlap: >= A, >= B and < A, >= C and < B. Alternatively you can use the sequential nature of CASE and simplify it to: >= A, >= B, >= C.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you put `Marks` into `GROUP BY` clause which makes it return all records (as well as do the summing). Remove it from `GROUP BY`

```
DECLARE @A_G INT, @B_G INT, @C_G INT, @D_G INT
SET @A_G = 40
SET @B_G = 30
SET @C_G = 10
INSERT INTO RESULTS ( QPaper_ID, Marks,Student_ID, Class, Grade)
select QPaper_ID, sum(Marks), Student_ID, Class,
case
when  sum(Marks) > @A_G then 'A'
when sum(Marks) between @B_G and @A_G then 'B'
when sum(Marks) between @C_G and @B_G then 'C'
else  'D'
END
from ANSWERS where QP_ID = 1000 and Login_ID = 'a'
GROUP BY QPaper_ID, Student_ID, Class
```

Comment: thanks. but the problem is that when I run this query in SQL it works (i.e inserts only 1 record) but when I try this same on the front-end (VB2012) 2 same records are inserted.

Comment: That's weird. Can you try to run just the select part of the query above from the code and see how many records it returns?